# SharePoint 2013 Webparts Installation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, web-part, 2007

I am migrating from MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

Can any one share The List of web parts that are present in MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010 which are Removed from SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? or, was the answer provided a sufficient response? Please mark the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft published the [changes between versions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx), which outlines several deprecated web part(s). For example, Web Analytics Web Part, was deprecated. As far as your standard publishing features, visual web parts, XSLT web part, list web parts, etc, they should all exist.

If you are missing a particular web part, you are currently unable to locate?